# .NET - Database bridge connection

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, gac, remote-server

Due to company restrictions, by default, websites aren't allowed to connect to the database directly. Today, most of new tools that we develop are done like that:

Website server (which is on a DMZ) ----> WCF Server -----> Database

Now we have to expose a legacy tool on that DMZ which uses a .DLL to do the database communication, but as the website server doesn't even have access to the database directly, connection would obviously fail.

Is there an easy way which I can, for example, point that persistence DLL on a remote server, reference that dll remotely and then access the database using the remote server?

I was searching about the GAC but seems like you can only use it locally.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this. You can expose methods of this dll as wcf service interface or use .net remoting to call this dll remotely.

Comment: I think the sysadmins would have a heart attack if they discovered you could!

Comment: This is valid approach from point of view of that company rule. And, if it is realised correctly, it improve security of database.

Comment: Thats what i tought. Thanks a lot!